# How to keep this table from re-rendering rows

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a table that gets rendered by Knockout

```
<table data-bind="visible: program">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Post</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Odds</td>
            <!--ko foreach: options -->
            <td data-bind="visible: value, text: name"></td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: program() ? program().item: []">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: place"></span>
            </td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: odd"></span></td>

            <!--ko foreach: $parent.options -->
            <td data-bind="visible: value">
                <span data-bind="text: $parent[prop]"></span></td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This table is rendered according to an observable I have (program). 'program is updated via ajax calls and then assignment (program(ko.mapping.fromJS(prg))).

program has a array of items, the item count varies in size, but each item always have the needed fields.

I imagine there is a way I can set this up so that Knockout only renders for new things.

For example if my current program has 6 items in it, that creates a table with 6 rows, if i get a different program that also has 6 items in it, then the table shouldnt actually re-render the table just use whats already there. If then i have a 7 item program it would only render the single row it needed. And if 5 items came in the one after that it would simply remove the 2 it isn't using

Does this sound possible? or am I off base?  ** Also my example above has been reduced for ease, the table does also contain a few ko.computed functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `repeat` binding does exactly that. It only renders new rows when the array gets larger:

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-bind="repeat: program() ? program().item: []">
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: $item().place"></span>
        </td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: $item().name"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: $item().odd"></span></td>

        <!--ko foreach: options -->
        <td data-bind="visible: value">
            <span data-bind="text: $item()[prop]"></span></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

See https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat

Comment: This looks interesting and promising and will definitely look into using it, but just for knowledge's sake can I not accomplish this with the normal standard set of bindings?

Comment: I fixed an issue with the inner foreach by removing/replacing the `$parent` references. That's because the `repeat` binding doesn't create a child context.

Comment: You could try to use `foreach`. Something like `foreach: ko.utils.range(0, program() ? program().item.length-1 : 0)`. Then `$data` within the `foreach` would be the index. So you could access items in your array with `$parent.program().item[$data].place`.